# Error Call to a member function find() on a non-object SIMPLEHTMLDOM

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am trying to get some contents from website. but I am getting error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in
>   C:\webs\BuyersGuide_webservice\ebay_crawler_sw.php on line 13

Here is the code

```
include_once 'simple_html_dom.php ';

$sw = $_GET['search_word'];     //getting search word
$sw = str_replace(' ','+',$sw);
$url = "http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html_trksid=p2050601.m570.l1311.R1&_nkw=".$sw."&_sacat=0&_from=R40";
$html = file_get_html($url);
$sw_c = $html->find('table[class=li rsittlref]',0);

$sw_l = $sw_c->find('a',0);         //first listed hyperlink from search word 
$url = $sw_l->href;     //- setting target url
```

When I check my code by giving static URL like this

```
$url="http://www.ebay.com/itm/Apple-iPhone-4S-16GB-White-Factory-Unlocked-Smartphone-/200926045964?pt=Cell_Phones&amp;hash=item2ec820270c";
```

for fetching then I get proper output. So no problem with scraping code.

Comment: This means that `file_get_html()` failed and returned `false`. That library has a size limit on the amount it will parse, how big is the response to that query?

Comment: And are you sure the URL is valid? Have you tried doing `file_get_contents()` and checking that it returns something?

Comment: i checked url n its working..
n regarding size i want to scrap http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_trksid=p2050601.m570.l1311.R1&_nkw=apple+iphone+4s&_sacat=0&_from=R40 --this url

Comment: The size limit is 600K, and that URL returns about 175K, so it should be OK.

Comment: When I hard-code that URL, it works for me.

Comment: whats the solution then ;(